# how to rotate my Graphic Tablet from landscape to portrait mode?

Tags: graphics, tablet

I have the Genius tablet 608x Graphic Tablet. it works fine in every sketching and painting software, what I need is to rotate the tablet so I can handle it in my left arm as a tall blanksheet and draw with the other hand. I want if as if I can switch the coordinates X to be -Y and Y to be X

Comment: If simply rotating the device doesn't work.  I am going to take a wild guess and say the device simply does not support this feature.

Comment: Ramhound's guess is correct. According to the [user manual](http://download.geniusnet.com/2011/Tablet/Manual%20V1.3.1.2.zip), this graphic tablet does not appear to have customizable axis settings.

Comment: Your display driver might have a rotation option. You could then make rotate the monitor to match the tablet, then rotate your final design to the desired configuration...